# If my pipeline rekeys elements - how do I get values for one key in the same worker without GroupByKey?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Let's say I have a pipeline, and I have a series of `ParDo` operations where element keys change. How can I ensure that elements for the same key some to the same worker without having to do a GroupByKey with windowing?

```
input_pcoll = p | beam.ReadFromXYZ(...)

rekeyed_pcoll = (input_pcoll
                 | beam.FlatMap(some_operation)
                 | beam.Map(lambda x: (compute_new_key(x), x['value'])))
```

After this, I would like to have elements of the same key go to the same worker without having to run a `GroupByKey` that uses windowing or triggering.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accomplish this.

The first one is by doing a `GroupByKey`, and having a trigger that triggers after every single element. Something like so:

```
keys_together_pcoll = (rekeyed_pcoll 
                       | beam.WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows()
                                         trigger=AfterCount(1)) 
                       | beam.GroupByKey()
                       | beam.FlatMap(lambda x: x[1]))

result_pcoll = (keys_together_pcoll 
                | beam.ParDo(DoFnWithElementsInCorrespondingWorkers()))
```

Granted, this is a little awkward.

---

Another way to do this is to make your DoFn stateful. This will force the runner to shuffle the elements into their corresponding workers by key. Something like this:

```
class DoFnWithElementsInCorrespondingWorkers(beam.DoFn):
  UNUSED_STATE = BagStateSpec('unused', VarIntCoder())

  def process(self,
              element,
              unused=beam.DoFn.StateParam(UNUSED_STATE)):
    # .. My processing


result_pcoll = (rekeyed_pcoll
                | beam.ParDo(DoFnWithElementsInCorrespondingWorkers()))
```

**Why does this happen?**

Remember that in Beam (and Flink, and similar systems), state is organized *by key*, so if you insert a stateful DoFn, Beam will recognize that elements need to be shuffled into the correct workers according to their keys.